# Unable to setup JavaFx platform in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, javafx, netbeans-7, java-8, javafx-8

I am using JDK 8 Early access (Build 90) with Netbeans 7.3 in windows but while enabling JavaFx in Java platform it says **JavaFx platform is not correctly defined**. I tried to give the jre8 path but still the error continues. The error is not shown when I set the JavaFx runtime to JRE 1.7 but in that case my JavaFx code is compiled by JDK8 but it tried to run using JRE7 ending up with incomparable class version error .

Note that I need to use JDK 8 for my experimental project which needs some latest features , so moving back to JDK 7 is not an option. Also Running the jar separately in command line every time I compile using netbeans  will take a lot of time reducing productivity.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans 7.3 doesn't support JavaFX 8.

NetBeans 7.3 is incompatible with JavaFX 8 because it looks for the JavaFX classes in the wrong place.  See this [JavaFX mailing list post for details](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-January/005677.html).  There is a corresponding bug in NetBeans to fix it to look for JavaFX classes in a new location, but it was not deliberately not addressed in NetBeans 7.3 (I can't find the bug in the NetBeans bug tracker to reference here, but I recall seeing it earlier).

I have managed to hack some of the NetBeans 7.3 configuration so that it can be used to develop JavaFX 8, but I don't want to publish that here because the hack is too fragile to be worthwhile.

On Oracle JavaFX forums ([thread: which IDE for JavaFX 8](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2536856)), other users have reported success using a [NetBeans nightly build with JavaFX 8](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/), though I haven't tried that configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with nightly build 201305192300 which accepted JRE 8 as for FX runtime but I could not start netbeans with JDK8 as platform (crashes at splash screen while loading cached objects), if I launch netbeans with jdk 7 , then i get error while running the javafx app even after selecting JDK 8 for the project. It says "you need latest JRE to run the code"

Comment: Try cross posting to the [Oracle JavaFX forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1385) or the [NetBeans forums](http://forums.netbeans.org).  Perhaps some of the NetBeans users there can assist you and explain how they are able to use JavaFX 8 with NetBeans.

Comment: I don't have an account in above portal so sent email to users@netbeans.org, lets see.

Comment: BINGO ! Looks like your latest edit to the answer helped me , Because I did not find jfxrt.jar in jre8's lib directory I choose jfr.jar (assuming its the replacement and abbr of  JavFxRuntime ). I was wrong , when I selected jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar looks like its running my javafx program with FX8 even though start my netbeans with JDK 7. I will confirm this when I test it completely and mark this question answered :) Thanks a lot. However launching Netbeans with JDK8 us still an issue and will post a diff question for this.